# Find commits in a side branch in Git not present in the main branch

Tags: git, branch

I have main branch and a side branch. Occassionally, the main branch is merged into the side branch, and also occasionally (usually a short time after the other merge), the side branch is merged back into the main branch.

```
M: ---------------------- ...
.      \     \  /   \
S:      ----------------- ...
```

I now want to have a log listing those commits on S not yet merged into M.

My solution idea is something like the following:

1. Find the most recent (according to the graph structure - it should be unique) commit reachable from (the tip of) M that is also reachable from the tip of S (i.e. when was S last merged into M?). Let's call it StoM
2. Find the most recent commit reachable from the tip of S that is also reachable from the tip of M (i.e. when was M last merged into S?). Let's call it MtoS.
3. For each commit in StoM..S, check whether it is in MtoS..M. If no, include it in the log.

First question: Will this yield a suitable result?

Second question: How can it be done in Git? Is it efficient? Are there better ways?

Comment: `git help revisions`

Answer (score 0):

`git log S ^M` will list all commits in `S` but not in `M`. It's exactly the same as `git log M..S`.